# Skorohod representation theorem with given marginal distribution

Tags: probability, weak-convergence

Consider the separable space $A\times B$, and let $\mu_n, \mu$ be probability measures on it. 
\begin{equation}
\mbox{Assume that the marginal laws of $\mu_n, \mu$ on $B$ are all the same!}
\end{equation}
If $\mu_n$ weakly converge to $\mu$, can we construct a sequence of random vectors $(X_n, Y)$ converging almost surely to $(X, Y)$ such that ${\rm Law}(X_n, Y)=\mu_n$ and ${\rm Law}(X, Y)=\mu$?